# Renaming an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, build, app-store

I want to rename my IPhone App from `com.domain.OldApp` to `com.domain.NewApp`.

I renamed the project in XCode and this caused the application identifier to change as expected to `com.domain.NewApp` and related build settings:

```
Bundle Identifier
com.cityoflondonconsulting.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
Bundle Name
${PRODUCT_NAME}
```

But I can't Archive because the distribution cert was for the old App name.

If I generate a new distribution cert, I need a new app id which is technically a new app in the App Store. Should I just leave the Project at the old name in Xcode? This will keep the old App Id `com.domain.OldApp`, which is how the app is identified in the app store -- or is it by Application Id number?

Then I could just change the fields where the app name appears to the user, such as Under the Icon and Search Results.

So

- change the Target > Build Settings > Bundle Display Name.
- when I submit the new version to the App Store I can edit the app name.

Is this right and if so am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go into itunesconnect and rename your project then download a new mobileprovision etc.

Comment: this would work if you want a completely new app in the app store but I wanted to keep the ratings, comments etc.

Answer (score 2):

The actual app name you use doesn't have to be related to the Bundle. The name of my app is different from the bundle and I've not had any issues getting published.

Comment: hardest bit was renaming the project BACK to old name in buggy Xcode 4 :)

Comment: fixed it by NOT RENAMING XCODE PROJECT
Only change Bundle display name in Project settings. This will change name under the icon and in Search results.

When you upload a new version. Enter version info and before you press UPLOAD BINARY click on EDIT button beside APP Metadata (not the marketing text the section above it).

In there you can change the App Name.

I use New App Name (formerly Old App Name) so customers wont panic when after update their fav app disappears and new one appears.

after few versions will remove the (formerly...) part